# How to take screenshot of a div and insert the value to model's property ASP .NET Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a banner creator. User changes the photos and captions dynamically, but i have to store all the texts and pictures in a SQL table so i created a model for it. When i click the save button, I want the banner div to be saved as jpeg file in my projects img folder, then it has to be passed to my models "Photo" property to be stored.

My View

```
@model HPBanner1ViewModel
<div class="row" id="canvas1">
                My Picture Here
            </div>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="HPBannerType1" asp-action="Create" method="post">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="PromosyonMetin" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Metin</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea asp-for="PromosyonMetin" type"="text" class="form-control" id="metinsrc" placeholder="Bol kabaklı mücver menüsü..." onKeyPress="copyText()"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Fiyat" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Fiyat</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">₺</span>
                                <span class="input-group-text">0.00</span>
                            </div>
                            <input asp-for="Fiyat" type="text" class="form-control" id="fiyatsrc" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest lira)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <p><b>Banner Resmi</b></p>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input asp-for="BannerPicture" type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                            <label asp-for="BannerPicture" class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <input asp-for="LogoURL" type="hidden" value="@Model.LogoURL">
                <input asp-for="RestaurantName" type="hidden" value="@Model.RestaurantName">
                <input asp-for="RestaurantID" type="hidden" value="@Model.RestaurantID">
                <input asp-for="CreationDate" type="hidden" value="@DateTime.Now">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <a id="savebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Oluştur</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
```

I use this code below to download the image but i couldn't find how to save it to my projects img folder and take the path to my model property . How can i do this ?

```
 $('#savebutton').click(function () {

        html2canvas($("#canvas1").get(0)).then(function (canvas) {

;
                    var aw = document.createElement('a');
                    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
                    aw.href = image;
                    aw.download = '@Guid.NewGuid()-@Model.RestaurantName-@DateTime.Now-HP1MOB.jpg';
            aw.click();


        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ajax to pass the image and imageName to controller where you could upload files and save path to database.

Javascript:

```
$('#savebutton').click(function () {

    html2canvas($("#canvas1").get(0)).then(function (canvas) {

        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        var data = {
            imageData: image,
            imageName: '@Guid.NewGuid()-@Model.RestaurantName-@DateTime.Now-HP1MOB.jpg'
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/SaveImage',
            data: data,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Image saved successfully !');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnv;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv,ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public  void SaveImage(string imageData,string imageName)
    {
        //save to Myapp/images folders
        //replace filepath with your own path to store files      
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.ContentRootPath, "images", imageName);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))

            {
                imageData = imageData.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
            //...
            //save path into database 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ! This seems like a proper approach